# how to write if else condition in the right form

Tags: javascript

how to write simple `if` take the first expression. Example bellow,  my code is looks like to much. 
   i mean first condition `email.val()`  and second  `!validateEmail(email.val())` with or expression. my big question is how to detect that first or second condition is executed ?

```
if(email.val() == "" || !validateEmail(email.val())){
    //call the condition again
    if(email.val() ==""){
        $("#error").html("<p>Email Cant be empty</p>");
        $("#error").show();
        setTimeout(function(){$("#error").fadeOut();}, 2000)
    }else{
        $("#error").html("<p>Wrong email format</p>");
        $("#error").show();
        setTimeout(function(){$("#error").fadeOut();}, 2000)
    }
    email.focus();
}
```

so I don't need to call this `if` again

```
if(email.val() == ""){
    $("#error").html("<p>Email Cant be empty</p>");
    $("#error").show();
    setTimeout(function(){$("#error").fadeOut();}, 2000)
}else{
    $("#error").html("<p>Wrong email format</p>");
    $("#error").show();
    setTimeout(function(){$("#error").fadeOut();}, 2000)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I do that way.
It allow in future to add other errors message or easy change them if needed.

```
// separate messages values to avoid long texts in the nested if part
// and prevent them from being searched for in parts of code
//  where they can be scattered in several places, and possibly repeated

const errorMessage =
  { email_empty : '<p>Email Cant be empty</p>'
  , email_wrong : '<p>Wrong email format</p>' 
  }

var messageError = ''
if(email.val()==='')                   { messageError = errorMessage.email_empty }
else if ( !validateEmail(email.val())) { messageError = errorMessage.email_wrong }

if (messageError) {
  $("#error").html(messageError)
  $("#error").show()
  setTimeout(function(){$("#error").fadeOut();}, 2000)
  email.focus()
}
```

Comment: next level,  using object . cool , i thinks this is a good idea

Comment: but how if i have a lot more code so in js is using async and sometime the error not being execute/show?

Comment: @Sidik this is a very different question, to which there can be several answers, up to the point of creating a separate object to manage all the errors, we get out a lot from the simple question of stye for some if / else ..

Answer (score 1):

You have roughly

```
if (condition1 || condition2) {
    if (condition1) {
         foo();
    } else {
         bar();
    }
    moo();
}
```

The `else` can only trigger when `condition1==false` and `condition2==true`, hence you can write the same as

```
if (condition1) {
    foo();
    moo();
} else if (condition2) {
    bar();
    moo();
}
```

Comment: your first code as same as like mine bro, i mean is there a trick without call the same if(condition) . example on or expression is has 2 condition or more (condition1 and condition2), naa. . if one of them is true so hole inside the function is executed, how to now wich condition is execute ? without using if anymore(again).

Comment: @Sidik: "*your first code as same as like mine*" - this is why idclev wrote "*You have roughly*". He then explained how you could modify your code in order to do the check only once for each condition: using `else if`

Comment: @Sidik I dont completely understand you. The first snippet is the same as yours and the second shows how it can be done without nested `if`

Answer (score 0):

So, as I see you're validating an email, there are two options you can look to avoid the nested if-else block or basically repeating your code again.

- **User Regex Expression**: You can validate email, and check if it's empty as well.

```
if(!regexPat1.test(email)) {
   // Do something
}
if(!regexPat2.test(email)) {
   // Do something
}
```

- **Use nest condition** : With this you can avoid rewriting same condition again.

```
if(email.val().trim() !=="") {
   if(!validateEmail(email.val().trim()) {
      //Throw invalid email error
   }else {
     // Do something
}
}else {
      // Trow empty value error
}
```

**There can be better solutions as well but I think this solves your doubt.**

Answer (score 0):

Simple rearrangement of your existing code.

```
if(email.val() == "") {
  $("#error").html("<p>Email Cant be empty</p>");
  $("#error").show();
  setTimeout(function(){$("#error").fadeOut();}, 2000);
  email.focus();
} else if (!validateEmail(email.val()) {
  $("#error").html("<p>Wrong email format</p>");
  $("#error").show();
  setTimeout(function(){$("#error").fadeOut();}, 2000);
  email.focus();
}
```

Comment: I'd say `else` should be `else if`, but it actually doesn't really differ in substance from [idclev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62020329/7831383)

Comment: i have the same think write this code, but i have i lot 'if' for validation. so i need to make it in one block code. like my question how to know wich condition is executed and triger it.